# Only Find and Copy the Images referenced in the CSS File using Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I've got a single page webapp (index.html), I built this using a responsive template I purchased so the template came with 100s of icons and images that I could use.

I pick and choose which images during the development stage, but when it comes to building a version of the app to deploy I need to manually go through the main CSS and HTML file and make a list of images used and copy them over. This is not the ideal solution of course and I'd like to automate this "find and build" stage.

The structure of the app is like so:

```
images/
------ icons/
------ logos/
------ tab/
------ slides/

css/
------ compiled/main.css

js/
------ main.js

index.html
```

I've been looking for a Grunt plugin that can go through my only main CSS file (compiled/main.css) and find all the images I ended up using. This CSS file is fairly large. It should then copy only those images into a "build" folder which looks like so:

```
build/
------ images/
------ css/
------ js/

index.html
```

Within the "build/images" folder it should also maintain the folder structure as needed in CSS so the reference dont break.

e.g. when I run the task:

it finds this snippet in the main.css file -

```
#hero.bg {
 background-image: url("images/slides/hello.jpeg");
}
```

and makes a folder like so:
"build/images/slides"

and copies the 'hello.jpeg' into it.

Does anyone if there is such a Grunt plugin already available, if not, I could write it but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

If possible, I'd like to take it one step further and also look in the index.html file for image links and copy them over too.

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking into this @Vishwanath, but by the time you had posted your code link I had written most of the plugin, so went ahead and released it to npm.

Its here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-img-find-and-copy

And code is here:
https://github.com/newbreedofgeek/grunt-img-find-and-copy

As described, its a simple plugin that you can point your source HTML and CSS files and it will scan these files for only images and copy them to your build folder whilst maintaing paths. It will be very useful for people who have 100s of images in their project but want to automate the task to only copy the used images to a build. I've tested it with my own website project and it works fine but there may be some issues which if raised I will fix.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I created a grunt plugin  [grunt-collect-css-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-collect-css-images) after your question. (*Got to learn few things along the way*).

Use it like following

```
grunt.initConfig({
  collect_css_images: {
    custom_options: {
      files: {
        'dest': ['*.css', 'level-1-dir/**/*.css']
      }
    }
  }
});
```

With above, all css files in the current directory and subdirectories of level-1-dir directory will be parsed for the images and all those images will be copied into dest directory as they are in the original directory hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for this @vishwanath - in theory this works, unfortunately it does not seem to do the job in my scenario. There are a few issues, looking at your code, you use 'background-image' to locate images, I need a more robust way, so I modified it to look for 'url' and then filter out things like fonts/css etc and only keep images files. Also the regex snippets you had do not seem to work so I had to replace them. I've hacked at your plugin and got it working for my need, I can make it more robust but I dont think you have put your code up on github for me to contribute?

Comment: It's on github... You can submit a pull request.... Check the npm page for link to github...

Comment: https://github.com/vishwanatharondekar/grunt-collect-css-images the correct link.... I'll update this in npm package as well...